# How/Where do I install storm door in a 9" deep door jamb with Pilasters?

Tags: storm-door

My front exterior door is inside a 9" jamb/pocket.  The door installation should be pretty straight forward, however there is not currently a storm door, so I dont have an example of how the new storm door should be installed.

Door I am installing is standard 4 9/16 external door (pre-hung) and there are some wood pieces extending the jamb through to the exterior brick of the house.

One the exterior of the door are pilasters, crosshead, and pediment.

What I am trying to figure out is Where can I mount the storm door?  There is no brickmold like in every install video I have watched.  Also, If I tried this, there would be an 8" gap between the storm door and exterior door.

(Pilasters removed, so there will be an additional 2" when reinstalled)

[image: door1]

[image: door2]

Comment: Any chance of a picture?  Is it 9" of brick in front of the door right now?

Comment: Remember there will pilasters which are an additional 2" thick mounted to the brick wall surrounding this door.
https://ibb.co/D4dVZpm
https://ibb.co/b2nRdnY

Comment: @mikalsan -- as in decorative pilastering then? (as an aside: I'm not a big fan of architectural "plant ons" of that nature)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, it is decorative.  I removed all the old rotted wood stuff and ordered foam/pvc replacement.  It will never rot again.

Comment: @JPhi1618, the current depth of interior wood and exterior brick is 9".  When pilasters reinstalled, it will be over 11"

Comment: @JPhi1618 Do you have any indication where the storm door should be mounted?  Can I install it inside the opening, or does it need to be installed on the outside somehow, next to the pillasters?

Answer (score 1):

The storm door should be installed on the existing door jamb, not the pilaster extensions.  This would be the "standard" place to install it, and it should be structurally sound already because its holding the main door in place.

You may be able to install it on the pilasters, but they would have to be attached very well to the brick, also cover the top of the opening, and have a proper jamb at the bottom.